# I can't access wcf service using net.tcp://<servicename>

Tags: wcf, net.tcp

I'm using IE8 and can't connect to my WCF service using net.tcp. I'm able to access the same service with http binding just fine. I got two binding enabled in app.config (net.tcp, http). Can anyone tell me if there is a settings that I need to set/play with for viewing service using net.tcp in IE.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot connect to a WCF service using the `netTcpBinding` through IE.

What you need is a "real" WCF client app, or something like [WCF Test Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx) which is shipped with WCF in the box - just find it and start using it!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a HTTP base address, for your service and a mexTcpBinding endpoint.